# "pip install models" fails with error code 1 "No module named 'base'

Tags: python, windows, module, model, radix

Using Python 3.9 on Windows 10

I need to import module "TSheets" but it throws an exception on one of its dependencies:

`from tsheets.api import TSheets`

Exception has occurred: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'models'

When I try to install models

`pip install models`

I get the output

```
Collecting models
  Using cached models-0.9.3.tar.gz (16 kB)
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: 'c:\python39\python.exe' -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\rober\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-utzl8ihq\\models_a160fe5c40f44b6180918e508f09440a\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\rober\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-utzl8ihq\\models_a160fe5c40f44b6180918e508f09440a\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base 'C:\Users\rober\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-pip-egg-info-ijs4wmiu'
         cwd: C:\Users\rober\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-utzl8ihq\models_a160fe5c40f44b6180918e508f09440a\
    Complete output (7 lines):
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "C:\Users\rober\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-utzl8ihq\models_a160fe5c40f44b6180918e508f09440a\setup.py", line 25, in <module>
        import models
      File "C:\Users\rober\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-utzl8ihq\models_a160fe5c40f44b6180918e508f09440a\models\__init__.py", line 23, in <module>
        from base import *
    ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'base'
    ----------------------------------------
WARNING: Discarding https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/92/3c/ac1ddde60c02b5a46993bd3c6f4c66a9dbc100059da8333178ce17a22db5/models-0.9.3.tar.gz#sha256=b5aa29c6b57a667cda667dd9fbd33bbd15c14cc285e57dda64f4f4c0fd35e0ae (from https://pypi.org/simple/models/). Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.
```

I've seen similar issues that turned out to be path issues on Windows, but I'm not sure how to fix this particular case.

My Python 3.9 installation is at the path **C:\Python39** to avoid any Windows user issues.

I also get errors when I try

```
pip install base
```

Thanks for any ideas or pointers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That `models` package on PyPI is not related to `TSheets`. See this issue:

https://github.com/TSheetsTeam/api_python/issues/7

According to a comment installing it from the github repo should fix it:

```
pip install --upgrade git+https://github.com/TSheetsTeam/api_python.git@301666970a2b70bb43b712923b8e48c412fda13a#egg=tsheets
```

Comment: Thanks! That fixed it. Next time I'll make sure to check out the package history and notes.